# Draw line with connector to text using CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to draw this kind of line using CSS only?

```
         This line
 __________|_____________
|                        |
|                        |
```

or

```
|                        |
|                        |
└────────────────────────
            |
         This line
```

I'm terrible at drawing using simple text but in picture ideally I want this to be like this:

[image]

Or like this

[image]

It can be dynamic depend on the size of the div that is pointing to.

Just to be clear to my question:

If this is possible to draw the same line as example above using plain CSS or I have to use image then scale them accordingly?

Example of final result that I want:

[image]

Comment: Maybe a foolish approach: you could properly use a `div`, which contains 3 other `divs` (a top one with a width of 100% and two `divs` below with a width of 50% each; for your first example) and set their borders accordently. But there might be better solutions than this one ;)

Comment: This can be done but it all depends on the HTML that you need to mark-up your content.  Can you give an example?

Comment: @MarcAudet not sure if you're asking about HTML example or mockup example? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/n5v3bx9nnjkdpzf/qgi1r-2j.png

Comment: Post your image (convert to jpg first), it helps to explain a bit more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: certainly doable with svg.

Comment: +1 for the SVG approach. Use a vector graphic that could be displayed in any width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do so using simple borders on positioned pseudo elements:

```
<p class="bracket">No account needed</p>
```

```css
.bracket {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.bracket:before, .bracket:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
}

.bracket:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
}

.bracket:after {
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/BVLx2/3/

Comment: Thanks! I like your approch. Really easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to do that is using negative margins, but using absolute positioning would work too. There are many ways to achieve this effect.

First the structure the code:

```
Content before.
<div class="rectangle">
    <div class="top line"></div>
    Content inside.
    <div class="bottom line"></div>
</div>
Content after.
```

I placed the `.top.line` as the first element and the `.bottom.line` as the last element because I'm using negative margins. If you used absolute positioning the placement in the HTML code wouldn't matter.

Then you pick a line length. Here I'll pick `20px`. Since I wouldn't want my line overlapping with the content before and after the div, I'll add that much of a vertical margin to the `.rectangle`.

```
.rectangle {
    margin: 20px 0;
    border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

The `.line` will have a right border with the same style, that right border is going to be the actual line. You can control the horizontal position by changing the width of the `.line`. In this case you want it on the middle, so `50%`, if you wanted it to be more to the right, `80%` etc.

```
.line {
    border-right: 1px dotted black;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Finally, in order to put the line out of the div, you use negative margins. The value of each margin must be equal the `border-width`plus the `padding` of the `.rectangle`. Since this `.rectangle` has no padding but a `border-width` of `1`, I add `1` to `20` and use a margin of `-21px`.

```
.top.line { margin-top: -21px; }
.bottom.line { margin-bottom: -21px; }
```

*Obs.*: Obviously you have to use `padding-top` + `border-top-width` for the `.top.line` and the bottom equivalents for the `.bottom.line`.

You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/QJNHL/

P.S.: I have nothing to do so here is the "set-like" effect posted using the same technique. http://jsfiddle.net/34yHs/

Comment: Your second example is really great

Answer (score 1):

Here's another version that uses rounded corners: http://jsfiddle.net/jwuB3/1/.

HTML:

```
<div class = "bracket">No Account Needed</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bracket {
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 301px;
    text-align: center;
    font: 10px/1 Sans-Serif;
}

.bracket:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -22px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px dotted #aaa;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.bracket:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: -12px;
    height: 10px;
    border-left: 1px dotted #aaa;
}
```